# Why is this simple CSS definition not working?

Tags: css, html, blueprint-css

**HTML**

```
<div class="span-24 last">
     Blah
</div>
```

*Some of you might recognize that I'm using a grid system ( defined by my blueprint's grid.css)*

**Not working**

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Working**

```
.last
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

What could be the problem, have I missed something important in my CSS learning ?

**Anser Wiki**

I got the answer to the question, I know it sounds stupid but there it is ->

I was using Eric Meyer's Reset.css, and it overrides the div's border property to 0.

You can **solve this by making sure that reset.css is the first stylesheet that gets loaded.**

Comment: Is there something in your grid.css what overrides your definition?

Comment: Maybe you are overriding the border property later on in your stylesheet? And if `span-24` or `last` clear the border property, your div selector won't be applied (lower specifity)

Comment: Both work for me - testing here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tpa6a/  Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Sorry, got the fault, was because of a reset stylesheet. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: You can just answer yourself (as you did), and mark it as answer. Or, if you think the question is not helpful, feel free to either deleting it or improving it by editing (even better!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to the question, I know it sounds stupid but there it is ->

I was using Eric Meyer's Reset.css, and it overrides the div's border property to 0.

You can solve this by **making sure that reset.css is the first stylesheet that gets loaded.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yzjJn/. Maybe some CSS is overriding its class...

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="span-24 last">
  Blah
</div>
```